# Isim not running

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-ise

I'm trying to run a full adder testbench. When i try to run the isim simulator it says "Running: Convert Schematics to HDL" then "No process Running". It doesn't even open the isim window.

I tried copying the schematics and the testbench in an other project but didn't do anything

Is there a place where i can upload my schematics and my testbench so someone could review it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows 10, navigate to the following directory:

```
installation directory \Xilinx\14.x\ISE_DS\ISE\gnu\MinGW\5.0.0\nt\libexec\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\collect2.exe
```

Locate the file named collect2.exe in this directory. Cut this file and paste it into a safe location as a backup. Keep it there until you're certain that everything is working as expected.

If did not work take a look at [this link](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/fpga/guide-getting-xilinx-ise-to-work-with-windows-8-64-bit/?PHPSESSID=m0bpt02feg07mv75ak81lg9ptj).